# updating two identical machines results in two different Darwin kernel versions reported

Tags: macos, software-update, kernel, darwin

I have two identical Mac Minis and I updated each with all available updates. This caused both machines to go from OS X 10.9.2 to OS X 10.9.4. 
However, `uname -a` reports different kernel versions for each machine:

On machine `oaxaca`:

```
Darwin oaxaca.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

On machine `morelia`:

```
Darwin morelia 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Why does morelia have a higher kernel version (13.3.0) than oaxaca (13.1.0)? On oaxaca when I open App Store and click Updates, I am told that no updates are available, so it's not clear to me how to get oaxaca to show the same kernel version.

Comment: An update on this: I updated both machines to OS X 10.9.5 and installed the command line updates, but oaxaca still reports kernel version 13.1.0, while morelia now reports 13.4.0.

Comment: Is the firmware identical? Did either system, or both systems, ever use a pre-release build of Mavericks?

Comment: Both systems have firmware version 2.8f1. They have never had a pre-release build of Mavericks installed, unless it was installed at the factory (which I'd hope is not the case).